# Is it necessary to install Python for react-native on windows for "react-native init AwesomeProject"?

Tags: python, react-native

I am trying to setup react-native on windows7.

I have following things installed:

```
C:\Windows\system32>node -v
v6.2.0    
C:\Windows\system32>npm -v
3.8.9    
C:\Windows\system32>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_60
```

I have not installed Python. When i try `react-native init AwesomeProject` only 2 things are downloaded in AwesomeProject: node_modules dir and

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "0.41.2"
  }
}
```

It is incomplete project. ReactNative0.41 Docs says

> We recommend installing Node.js and **Python2**.

Why Python is recommended with react-native? Does react-native requires python to clone the seed project?

I have installed following things as well:

- Android SDK
- Android SDK Platform
- Android Virtual Device
- Android 6.0 SDK tools
- Google APIs
- Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Python is needed. [Download the newest Python 2 release](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and install it.

The reason why it's used is because React Native's build system is 100% based on it. It is used to compile your source code and serve it during development mode. In the same way that some build systems are based in JS using, say, Webpack, theirs is just a collection of Python scripts.

Facebook, in general, relies on Python a lot for build workflows.

Comment: After installing python, i am able to download complete base project using react-native init command. But it seems confusing, **why python when cloning base project ?**. What kind of compilation is taking place here?

Comment: If you're having trouble, it's better to post exactly what you have tried and what kind of error message you got. As to "why Python", it's because their workflow scripts are based in Python, simply as that. It could be based in something else, like JavaScript, Bash, make, or something. They picked Python.

Comment: Exact problem is without python **react-native init project** command will download _node_modules_ directory with a _package.json_ as shown above.

Comment: Would python 3 work? I know I can try my self, but prefer advice as I am using already anaconda to do Machine Learning Python stuff and would not mess things up

Comment: @trocchietto yes