# Is python 3 compatible with react native? or should I install python 2 as documentation of react suggests it?

Tags: react-native

React native documentation says python2 is required but what if python3 is installed?

will I get errors in react native app if python3 is installed?

I am using windows 10 and I am going to run it on Android.
 also, I read python is necessary from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442732/is-it-necessary-to-install-python-for-react-native-on-windows-for-react-native).

Comment: try it and see...

Comment: I think OP question is licit. All the guides speak about python 2, this is odd.  Honestly as I am using windows less I do not necessary installations more I am happier, in fact is upvoted and few people are following him

Comment: I wanna know the answer too. Do you have try?

Comment: python3 and python2, both works well with react-native. In Ubuntu default installed  python version is `2.7`, and no need to install python 3 separately. :)

Comment: @avigil It is very easy to try. But i think he is asking this to save his time on development. I think not everyone has the helping mind. Actually very less people have such a mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. You can work with `react native` and `python 3`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Now it is mentioned,

> Python v2.7, v3.5, v3.6, v3.7, or v3.8

So I believe Python 3 should be good to go.

**Old Answer**

I would say if they have specifically mentioned Python 2 then there must be some reason. If you go to [this link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows), then you can see they have mentioned

> python (v2.7 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)

So there might be some compatibility issue in some module or something. Just check everything you require is working as expected.